# Sequence diagram for a function containing one object

Tags: class, uml, use-case, sequence-diagram

I know Sequence diagram is a interaction model so we need more than 1 object.
I made a class diagram with a `logIn()` function inside the `User` class then I documented all the use cases for the application.
Now I have to make sequence diagram for each function I documented.
I am a little bit confused if it is right or not.
This is the use case:

[image][image]

This is my logIn(username,password) sequence diagram
[image]

Comment: Why an SD? An Activity diagram will make much more sense for this. Pretty annoying what they teach out there...

Comment: to make our life difficult but I have to do it.

Comment: Does not make much sense to ask for help in such a situation. Good luck - and forget most of what they did teach once you got your graduation.

Answer (score 1):

A use case is a case of a user using a system. Therefore, you have at least two parties: The user and the system. If there are secondary actors involved you even have more.

So, the login command is sent from the user to the system.

Your system might have some internal representation of the user. But that is something that comes up much later during the design of the system and should not have any influence on the sequence diagram for a use case.

Comment: thank you so much for replying .. I added database as the second user for login I'll think about system too now